# find the largest positive integer $(k>2)$, such that sum of any two distinct numbers is ot divisible by their difference.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, integers

For $A=\{1,2,\cdots ,2012\}$  , find the largest positive integer $(k>2)$ such that it is possible to choose $k$ elements in $A$ whose sum of any two distinct numbers among the k chosen numbers is not divisible by their difference.

I think it has something to do with divisibility by $3$. $2$ different numbers that divide by $3$ leave a remainder of $2$ whose sum is not divisible by the difference.

Answer (score 3):

Define $B$ as a subset of $A$ such that the sum of any two numbers in $B$ is not divisible by their difference.

Observe, we can choose only one of the three consecutive numbers, $x$, $x+1$ and $x+2$ to be elements of $B$. Therefore, $k=|B|\le \left\lceil \dfrac{2012}{3}\right\rceil=671$. It remains to show that such a set $B$ with $671$ elements exists. The following construction proves that $k_{\max}=671$.
$$B=\{1,4,7,\cdots,2011\}\implies |B|=671$$

Comment: Why we can chose only one of the three consecutive numbers $x,x+1, x+2$? Can you explain fo me more details?

Comment: Try choosing two of the three consecutive numbers. Does it satisfy the conditions ?(check their sum and difference). Hope it helps :)